# Android 5.0 Tabhost action bar?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'd like to have an actionbar (including a menu) with below some tabs like this:

[image: Left screen]

How is this possible? I know Tabhost is decapricated, but I can't find a suitable alternative..

Comment: Did you look at new [design support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design)?

Comment: @Serikov I would like to have something like the "Default app bar and fixed tab bar" image at this site: http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage .. But I can't find how I can do this :(

Answer (score 1):

Chris Banes has recently open sourced a demo application using the new Design Support Library called cheesesquare which contains the functionality you are looking for.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design

Comment: Thanks for the info. When trying to add the dependencies I get a error... `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-design:22.0.0` .. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to open up your SDK Manager and update the Android Support Repository and Android Support Library.